# React - how to wait for API response to return component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to react and I am building a page component that returns data from an API call and passes the values to my return statement. My page continues to return as blank because the page loads before the variables are returned from the API. I am wondering, how can I wait to render the page until my API has returned a response? The two variables are initialized as so and are not updated until the API response

```
var userData
    const [customer_email, setEmail] = useState();
    const [newuserid, setUserId] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    userData = Cookies.get("user-data");
    if (userData) {
        console.log("Userdata !== null");
        try {
            userData = JSON.parse(userData);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        setEmail(userData.email);
        setUserId(userData.userID);

    }
}, []);

function getCustomer() {
    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "x-guid": "......",
            "x-api-key": ".....",
        },
    };
    if (customer_email != "" && customer_email != undefined) {
        try {
            console.log("email inside fetch =", customer_email);
            fetch(
                `https://exampleapi/customers?customer_email=${customer_email}&customer_id=${newuserid}`,
                options
            )
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((response) => console.log(response))
                .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}

if (customer_email) {
    console.log("get customer");
    getCustomer();
}
```

The component return statement:

```
return (
        <>
            {customer_email && (
                <section>
                    <div
                        id="identification"
                        data-authenticated="true"
                        data-email={customer_email}
                        data-id={newuserid}
                        style={{ display: "none" }}
                    ></div>
                 </section>
                <div>
                     ........{irrelevant html here}
                 </div>
            )}
         );
```

Note---- This is not a class, it is a function component

Comment: It would be great to see how you are making the API call. Please share the full functional component code. Normally, if you are using state and correctly setting it the component should re-render as soon as the state changes

Comment: Try this: `data-email={customer_email || ''}` and `data-id={newuserid || ''}`. I guess those are the values you are going to receive from the API.

Comment: @assembler Updated the question, thank you both

Comment: You don't want to "wait" to render until an API call is done. You typically have it render the different states it's in: `[initial, loading, loaded, error]`. You can show nothing or show a loading indicator, etc.

Comment: You are not updating the state on the API response. Also you should `!==` instead of `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like this where you have a loading state that you set to true when the response from the API has been resolved, which will re-render the component.

Note: This code will not work if you copy and paste. It's just a representation of the pattern you should use.

```js
    var userData
        const [customer_email, setEmail] = useState();
        const [newuserid, setUserId] = useState();
        cost  [hasLoaded, setHasLoaded] = useState(false);

    function getCustomer() {
        const options = {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "x-guid": "......",
                "x-api-key": ".....",
            },
        };
        if (customer_email != "" && customer_email != undefined) {
            try {
                console.log("email inside fetch =", customer_email);
                fetch(
                    `https://exampleapi/customers?customer_email=${customer_email}&customer_id=${newuserid}`,
                    options
                )
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((response) => console.log(response))
                    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        userData = Cookies.get("user-data");
        if (userData) {
            console.log("Userdata !== null");
            try {
                userData = JSON.parse(userData);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
            setEmail(userData.email);
            setUserId(userData.userID);

        }
    }, []);


   useEffect(async () => {
       if (!customer_email) return;
       console.log("getting customer")
   
       const customerData await getCustomer()
       if (customerData) setHasLoaded(true)
   }, [])


   return(
     <>
      {hasLoaded && <div>.....</div>}
     </> 
   )
```